# How do you insert propertized text with keymap and mouse-face

Tags: org-mode, text-properties

I am trying to insert propertized text that is clickable like this:

```
(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*test*")))
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (read-only-mode -1)
    (erase-buffer)
    (org-mode)
    (insert 
     (propertize "clickable"
         'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")
         'keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
               (define-key map (kbd "<mouse-1>")
                 (lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (message-box "clicked")))
               map)
         'mouse-face 'highlight
         'help-echo "Bad key, click to replace."))
    (read-only-mode +1))

  (display-buffer-in-side-window buf '((side . right))))
```

However, The keymap and mouse-face properties seem to be lost and I only see these properties:

```
There are text properties here:
  font-lock-face       (:foreground "red")
  fontified            t
  help-echo            [Show]

[back]
```

Am I missing some critical thing that causes these to be stripped out?

Comment: Indeed, org-mode is the culprit. Thanks.

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Changing my comment to a (partial) answer, as comments can be deleted at any time.)

If you comment out the sexp `(org-mode)` then your initial code works (except for the red text, for which you'd need to use property `face`, not `font-lock-face`, or else define font-locking for your buffer).

Maybe check which part of Org mode is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works to make clickable text like I wanted.

```
(let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*test*")))
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (read-only-mode -1)
    (erase-buffer)
    (org-mode)
    (insert-button "clickable" 'face '(:foreground "red")
           'keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                 (define-key map (kbd "<mouse-1>")
                   (lambda ()
                 (interactive)
                 (message-box "clicked")))
                 map)
           'mouse-face 'highlight
           'help-echo "Bad key, click to replace.")

    (read-only-mode +1))
  (add-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) '(mouse-face highlight))
  (display-buffer-in-side-window buf '((side . right))))
```

I am still not sure why the keymap and mouse-face properties get stripped in the original question though.

I guess the difference is this uses an overlay. If I use `insert-text-button` it also does not work as desired.